# Vuex commit does not trigger v-show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for the first time, I found that a [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) directive is not been triggered after mutation commit on the store

```
// store.js
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"

const states = {
    app: {
        init: "APP_INIT"
    }
}

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        appState: ""
    },
    mutations: {
        changeAppState (state, appState) {
            state.appState = appState
        }
    },
    getters: {
        isVisible: state => state.appState === states.app.init
    }
})
export { store }
```

**ComponentA.vue**

```
<template v-show="isVisible">
    <div id="componentA"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ComponentA",
        computed: {
            isVisible () {
                return this.$store.getters.isVisible
            },
            appState () {
                return this.$store.state.appState
            }
        },
        watch: {
            appState (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(`Changed state: ${oldVal} => ${newVal}`)
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.$store.commit("changeAppState", "APP_INIT")
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    #componentA {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

I've defined a `getter` `isVisible` which should evaluate to `true` if the `state.appState` property is equal to the string `APP_INIT`.
I thought that the commit on the mutation will trigger the reactive system and force a re-render of the view, but this is not happening. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives cannot be applied to the root `<template>` like that. You'd have to use an inner element:

```
<template>
  <div v-show="isVisible">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/py75wynnwm?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FComponentA.vue)

Also note the Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) state:

> Note that `v-show` doesn’t support the `<template>` element, nor does it work with `v-else`.

Comment: Or use the `v-show` directive on the component itself, say `<component-a v-show="isVisible"></component-a>`. You will have to move the `isVisible` getter.

Comment: Reading the v-if section from https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html, it says that it is possibile to apply v-if on template, so I thought it should work for v-show as well. I guess it’s a v-if only thing?

Comment: I answer myself, yes it’s definetely only working for v-if

Comment: Indeed, the Vue docs indicate `v-show` does not support `<template>`. I've updated the answer to indicate this.